# Controlling YARN memory settings within Apache Apex memory model

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-apex

I am seeing the following log from the web UI occasionally when my operators are getting killed. Is there any way I can control the memory settings that are used to communicate with YARN when negotiating a container ?

How does the typical YARN settings for a container heap and max memory relate to the Apex memory allocation model.

The info messages I see in the web UI are as follows:

```
Container [pid=14699,containerID=container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 6.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 14817 14699 14699 14699 (java) 1584 1654 6426968064 393896 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Xmx4429185024 -Ddt.attr.APPLICATION_PATH=hdfs://dwh109.qaperf2.sac.int.threatmetrix.com:8020/user/dtadmin/datatorrent/apps/application_1462863487071_0015 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data3/yarn/nm/usercache/root/appcache/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012/tmp -Ddt.cid=container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dhadoop.log.dir=/data3/yarn/container-logs/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012 -Ddt.loggers.level=com.datatorrent.*:INFO,org.apache.*:INFO com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer 
    |- 14699 14697 14699 14699 (bash) 1 2 108646400 303 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/default/bin/java  -Xmx4429185024  -Ddt.attr.APPLICATION_PATH=hdfs://dwh109.qaperf2.sac.int.threatmetrix.com:8020/user/dtadmin/datatorrent/apps/application_1462863487071_0015 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data3/yarn/nm/usercache/root/appcache/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012/tmp -Ddt.cid=container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dhadoop.log.dir=/data3/yarn/container-logs/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012 -Ddt.loggers.level=com.datatorrent.*:INFO,org.apache.*:INFO com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer 1>/data3/yarn/container-logs/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012/stdout 2>/data3/yarn/container-logs/application_1462863487071_0015/container_1462863487071_0015_01_000012/stderr   

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the operator requires more memory. You may add this property to have more memory allocated to the container. In properties.xml , for operator O in the application you may specify the property :

```
<property>
 <name>dt.operator.O.attr.MEMORY_MB</name> 
 <value>2048</value>
</property>
```

For more advance option, take look at the Physical Plan preparation code.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-apex-core/blob/ddb7471edd37ef228432c7d80e1e118368e68450/engine/src/main/java/com/datatorrent/stram/plan/physical/PhysicalPlan.java

For more troubleshooting guide, take a look at

http://docs.datatorrent.com/troubleshooting/#configuring-memory